# How to redirect to a reactjs component when clicking on a Menu Item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect

I am new to `Reactjs` i need to redirect to a specific component when clicking on a menu item.

I tried to use `/ComponentName` in the `href` but not working. `<a href="/Store">Stores</a>`.

**My Code:**

```
import React from 'react';

function Menu(){
    return (
        <div className='header-menu'>
           <nav>
              <div>
                  <ul>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                       <a className="nav-link" href="/Store">Stores</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
             </div>
           </nav>
        </div>
           )
```

Comment: Use `react-router-dom` package here's the link: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: Please try to use one of several routing packages to do this, `react-router-dom` is the most common one. We can help out if you get stuck on your next step.